# Transparent window changes look

Tags: java, window, transparency, look-and-feel

I'm trying to create a transparent window with a visible toolbar, and so far I have been able to do it except that the look and feel of the window changes from the normal OS look and feel to the default metal look. I was just wondering if there is a way around it.Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class NewClass2 extends JFrame{
    public NewClass2(){`enter code here`
        super("NewClass2");
        //setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));//this makes the window transparent
        setSize(new Dimension(300,200));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);//this stops an exception
            //from occurring with transparent windows, but changes look and feel.
        NewClass2 cls2=new NewClass2();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never set the look and feel you want to use, so Java defaults to the what ever it "thinks" should be the look and feel...which is typically metal.

Add...

```
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

before you create any UI elements.

Take a look [Modifying the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html) for more some more details

You should also make sure that your UI is started within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread in order to ensure that you don't hit any potential paint problems or other threading issues, have a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details